# How to get the length of chineses string in Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata, string-length

I would like to count the total number of a string in Chinese, and the values may include numbers or English `alphbet`.
I've used `length()` function in **`SQL`**, but the one Chinese word will take 2 bytes.

```
ex.
LENGTH('測試test')=8, expected answer:6 (X)

LENGTH('test')=4, expected answer:4 (O)
```

So, how can I get the right length of the string if English, numbers, and Chinese are included?

Comment: This works fine for me. You should check: #1 if the client character is set to UTF8 or UTF16 and #2 if you use the correct `LENGTH` function: `SELECT DatabaseName FROM dbc.functionsV WHERE FunctionName = 'LENGTH'` should return `td_sysfnlib`

Comment: thanks for the information.  The function is correct, but it still not work for me. I also checked CHARACTER_LENGTH() function (according to the website: http://lakenine.com/teradata-primer-for-sql-developers-character-functions/#character_length_attribute). Doesn't work, neither.